# Regex alternative for extracting numeric and non-numeric strings

Tags: c#, regex, linq, logic, alphanumeric

Using the below expression, I'm able to get the expected output and extract numbers or string and split to a string array.

```
Regex _re = new Regex(@"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

_re.Split("2323dfdf233fgfgfg ddfdf334").Dump();  //string can be any alphanumeric start with
```

How to achieve the same thing without using Regex? Do I need to parse each char and segregate? I have a large array of text which needs to be processed to extract but I cannot use regex as inputs provided.

Comment: Without regex? Then what *can* you use?

Comment: By using loop or linq or any alternate optimal solution.  so, it can not hit while processing large string.

Comment: So, what have you tried then?

Comment: So, why don't you want to use regex?  Regex *is* the optimal solution.  Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel and make extra work for yourself?

Comment: true, its best option to go with regex but as given instruction, need to implement  alternate option.

Comment: Looks like, some alternate need with `char.IsDigit` check for each char and prepare string array but it will be long to process and different permutation match to regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is fast enough. Check with larger strings.

```
string str = "2323dfdf233fgfgfg ddfdf334"; 

var strings = new List<string>();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var lastCharIsNumber = char.IsDigit(str[0]);

foreach (var c in str) {
    if (char.IsDigit(c) ) {
        if (!lastCharIsNumber) {
            strings.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
        lastCharIsNumber = true;
    }
    else {
        if (lastCharIsNumber) {
            strings.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
        lastCharIsNumber = false;
    }
    sb.Append(c);
}
strings.Add(sb.ToString());
strings.Dump();
```

Comment: `char.IsDigit` can be replaced with smth like `Predicate<char> IsNumber = (c) => c >= 48 && c <= 57;` , but this doesn't seem to be much faster.

Comment: Nice answer! +1. It's actually faster, compared to Linq, when dealing with large strings. One thing though: You can pretty much replace your `if..else` statement with a considerably shorter version _(without else)_: `if (char.IsDigit(c) != lastCharIsNumber) { lastCharIsNumber = !lastCharIsNumber; // .... }`.

Answer (score 2):

For a Linq solution, you can combine the use of [`Enumerable.Skip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [`Enumerable.TakeWhile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile) while checking for [`char.IsDigit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit) to determine whether the character is a digit or not. For example:

```
string inputString = "2323dfdf233fgfgfg ddfdf334";
var list = new List<string>();

int usedLength = 0;
while (usedLength < inputString.Length)
{
    bool isDigit = char.IsDigit(inputString[usedLength]);
    string item = string.Concat(inputString.Skip(usedLength).
                                            TakeWhile((c) => char.IsDigit(c) == isDigit));
    usedLength += item.Length;
    list.Add(item);
};
```

Then you can easily iterate through the list:

```
foreach (string item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output:**

```
2323
dfdf
233
fgfgfg ddfdf
334
```

Comment: Enumerable methods seem to slow down the performance incredibly. Better use simple loop as in my solution.